# how can i bind image in listbox

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a listbox on my page where i am checking the driver status if driver status is 1 then i change the font color in red Status 2 then i change color of font in listbox in green . Like that i want that i place a image with item in listbox if status will be 1 then i display a red image with that . How can i do that for you i am placing my aspx and c# code below

```
<asp:ListBox ID="ddlDriver" Width="100%" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlDriver_SelectedIndexChanged"
                                        runat="server" BackColor="White" Height="380px"></asp:ListBox>
```

C# Code for listbox item font color

```
 protected void ColorFillDrvier()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < ddlDriver.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        int drvierNo = Convert.ToInt32(ddlDriver.Items[i].Value);
        Drivers _driv = DataRepository.DriversProvider.GetByDriverNumber(drvierNo);

        if (_driv.DriverStatus == 1)
        {

            ddlDriver.Items[i].Attributes.CssStyle.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Color, "red");

        }
        else if (_driv.DriverStatus == 2)
        {

            ddlDriver.Items[i].Attributes.CssStyle.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Color, "green");

        }
        else if (_driv.DriverStatus == 3)
        {

            ddlDriver.Items[i].Attributes.CssStyle.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Color, "yellow");
        }
        else if (_driv.DriverStatus == 4)
        {

            ddlDriver.Items[i].Attributes.CssStyle.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Color, "blue");
        }
        else if (_driv.DriverStatus == 5)
        {

            ddlDriver.Items[i].Attributes.CssStyle.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Color, "black");
        }

    }

}
```

How can i do that . Thanks in advance for you all

Comment: This is the problem i am facing from sometime and i think this is the board where i can discuss

Comment: Maybe for you this is small but i am not geting answer so i post here

Comment: I am not saying about the question. The question is fine. But if you find an answer that solves your question, then you must accept it as well. That encourages everyone to answer your problem.